# htaccess not working as step wise rules defined

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My knowledge about htaccess says that once **[L]** flag is used, rules stand terminated and no further rules will be executed. But here dont know why rules are not working after i added following rule to my current htaccess.

```
 #### Redirect all non-file & non-directory url to Results.php ####
 RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^.*$ ./Results.php [L]
```

All valid urls e.g. `Job-Details.php` are also redirecting to Results.php script.

**Note :** I have already checked after restarting all services of wamp server & cleared cache.

**EDIT 1:-** I got to know after spending more than 1 day reading that i was not able to explain what i want as solution. Big apologies for that.

Now, clear thought is, after `Job-Details.php` url rewriting, url becomes like
`http://domain.com/7997` i want, that this url should not go to `Results.php` by default though it's non-existing file/directory name & should use `Job-Details.php` script in place of `Results.php`.

I have tried using following code but no positive results.

`Rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} [^0-9/]$`

How should i go? any expert advise?

**My complete htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

### Start rewrite and set basedir
RewriteEngine on
Rewritebase /Domain.com/

########### Redirect all non-file & non-directory url to Results.php ############
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ ./Results.php [L]

########### Remove php extension ####################
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

########### Job detail page extension remove ####################
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} Job\-Details\.php\?Job_ID\=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L,NE]

########### Result page extension ####################
#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} Results\.php\?url\=([A-Za-z0-9-_]+) [NC]
#RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L,NE]
```

I have tried searching logic behind this behavior but couldn't find any or i may have searched wrong pharse.

Comment: Your first rule matches everything and redirects all that is not a file name or a directory name to Results.php. Not further action is expected, because of the [L] flag and because this rule matches everything.

Comment: The L flag just exits   the current rewrite cycle . I think you are looking for the END?

Comment: @starkeen i am looking solution using all virtual links (not file/directory) redirected to `Results.php` Job-Details.php is the actual file which should not be redirected to Results.php. correct me if i am wrong here.

Comment: any help on this..